# Full Outer Join self with null values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, outer-join, self-join

I want to do a full outer self-join that includes nulls.  For example, if the table `Data` looks like:

```
N   Name   Val
--------------
1   ABC    8
1   DEF    7
2   ABC    9
2   XYZ    6
```

(where `N` is a general index column to enable a self-join on sequential groups) and I do:

```
SELECT COALESCE(a.n, b.n) as n, COALESCE(a.Name, b.Name) as Name, a.Val as A, b.Val as B
FROM Data a 
     FULL OUTER JOIN Data b on a.N = b.N - 1 and a.Name = b.Name
```

I want:

```
N  Name  A    B
---------------
1  ABC   8    9
1  DEF   7    NULL
1  XYZ   NULL 6
```

but what I get is more like a cross-join:

```
n  Name  A    B
--------------
1  ABC   8    9
1  DEF   7    NULL
2  ABC   9    NULL
2  XYZ   6    NULL
1  ABC   NULL    8
1  DEF   NULL    7
2  XYZ   NULL    6
```

How do I perform this full outer join in order to get the condensed self-join results?

(**Note:** In practice column `N` is a generalized index, so solutions that require naming the values of `N` aren't practical.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we want to handle a generalized self-join index column `N` let's extend the sample set a little further:

```
create table #Data (n int, name char(3), val int)
insert into #Data values (1, 'ABC',8)
insert into #Data values (1, 'DEF',7)
insert into #Data values (2, 'ABC',9)
insert into #Data values (2, 'XYZ',6)
insert into #Data values (3, 'ABC',9)
insert into #Data values (3, 'DEF',5)
insert into #Data values (3, 'XYZ',4)
```

For this sample we want the SQL to produce this output:

```
N  Name  A    B
---------------
1  ABC   8    9
1  DEF   7    NULL
1  XYZ   NULL 6
2  ABC   9    9
2  DEF   NULL 5
2  XYZ   6    4
```

The following code works on the general case:

```
SELECT COALESCE(a.n, b.n-1) as i, COALESCE(a.Name, b.Name) as Name, a.Val as A, b.Val as B
FROM #Data a 
    FULL OUTER JOIN #Data b ON a.N = b.N - 1 AND a.Name = b.Name
WHERE a.n < (SELECT MAX(n) FROM #Data) -- Deals with end index case
    OR (a.n is null AND b.n-1 IN (SELECT DISTINCT n FROM #Data))
ORDER BY COALESCE(a.n, b.n-1), Name
```

---

To see why this works, a good intermediate step is to note that when `a.N = 1` we want the rows where `n = 1` from:

```
SELECT COALESCE(a.n, b.n - 1) as n, COALESCE(a.Name, b.Name) as Name,
    a.Val as A, b.Val as B 
FROM #Data a
    FULL OUTER JOIN #Data b ON a.N = b.N - 1 AND a.Name = b.Name
```

Answer (score 1):

So far I've been only able to see doing this as a union. and a left and right join since the criteria of what you're after changes.

```
SELECT COALESCE(a.Name, b.Name) as Name, a.Val as A, b.Val as B
FROM Data a 
LEFT JOIN Data b on a.Name = b.Name   
   and B.N = 2
WHERE A.N = 1 
UNION 
SELECT COALESCE(a.Name, b.Name) as Name, a.Val as A, b.Val as B
FROM Data a 
RIGHT JOIN Data b on a.Name = b.Name   
   and A.N = 1
WHERE B.N = 2
```

Giving us:

```
+------+---+----+
| NAME | A |  B |
+------+---+----+
| ABC  | 8 |  9 |
| DEF  | 7 |    |
| XYZ  |   |  6 |
+------+---+----+
```

However this relies on a hardcoded N value which I don't think is that useful... working on better.

Comment: Yes, that's the trick: `N` is an index column to allow for sequential self-joins, so I can't use named values of `N`....

Comment: Just updated the question to make it clear that `N` is part of the output.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the code below:

```
create table Data (n int, name char(3), val int)

insert into data values (1, 'ABC',8)
insert into data values (1,   'DEF',    7)
insert into data values (2 ,  'ABC' ,   9)
insert into data values (2  , 'XYZ',    6)

SELECT COALESCE(a.Name, b.Name) as Name, a.Val as A, b.Val as B
FROM Data a 
     FULL OUTER JOIN Data b on a.N = b.N - 1 and a.Name = b.Name
```

The output is this:

[image]

There are nulls on both sides.

Comment: Oops ... yes, you're right; I was restricting my test data in a way that didn't show this.  I'm fixing the original question to reflect this.  (Note that it still doesn't join the way I want.)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
SELECT [Name]
       ,[1]
       ,[2]
FROM [table]
PIVOT
(
    MAX([val]) FOR [N] IN ([1], [2])
) PVT;
```

Comment: Clever.  But column `N` is a large index, so I need a generalizable case where I don't have to name each possible value of `N`.